# Removing three consecutrive dots and the following number from a string

Tags: r, gsub

I have data as follows:

```
myvec <- c("Some 1 sentence...113_the answer", "Some 3 sentence...1_the answer")
```

I would like to remove the three consecutrive dots and the following number from these strings, how should I do this?

I could do:

```
myvec <- gsub("\\...", "", myvec)
```

And then remove the numbers with regex, but this is a bit unsafe for my data (as there might be more numbers in the string that I need to keep as in the created example).

How should I remove the exact combination of three dots and a number?

**EDIT** Desired output:

```
myvec <- c("Some 1 sentence_the answer", "Some 3 sentence_the answer")
```

Comment: Does matching the three dots and all the following numbers work? You can use this regex for that: (\.\.\.\d+)

Comment: @AbhishekG Thank you for your comment, I get this error when using `gsub`,  `Error: '\.' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\."`

Comment: Maybe I should change some options in `gsub` ?

Comment: Unsure about the desired output, please add it to the question as you always should.See my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74651632/6574038), though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either do

```
gsub('\\.{3}\\d{1}', '', myvec)
# [1] "Some 1 sentence13_the answer" "Some 3 sentence_the answer"
```

or

```
gsub('\\.{3}.*_', ' ', myvec)
[# 1] "Some 1 sentence the answer" "Some 3 sentence the answer"
```

depending if you want to remove one digit or the entire number.

Answer (score 1):

`library(stringr)`

`myvec <- c("Some 1 sentence...113_the answer", "Some 3 sentence...1_the answer") str_remove_all(myvec,'\\.\\.\\.\\d')`

or

`str_remove_all(myvec,'\\.\\.\\.\\d{1,20}')`

`d{1,20}` means that you want to delete all following numbers if their number is from one to 20